# WF that writes info to another list looking to update the same item across it's originally created row

Tags: sharepoint-designer

This is a bit hard to explain.

First WF writes a newly uploaded documents name to another list.
Second WF inserts a date stamp when a user does there task to the same documents.

The WF's work but they write new entries (rows).

I'd like to figure out how to update each column in the list rather than make a new entry (row) for the same document as it moves through the process.

Example

User uploads a new document first WF writes a entry in listXYZ.

Second user does X to the document and date stamps it. The second WF writes a new entry in the listXYZ

I want the second WF to write info into it's appropriate column but not create a new entry in the list if that is possible.

No clue as to how to do this

TIA

Answer (score 0):

When the first WF runs and creates the item in listXYZ, you'll need to store the List Item ID that is associated with that in the original "trigger" list. Just use a hidden field that can be referenced easily via workflow.

Next, whenever the second workflow(s) need to update the item in listXYZ based on the original list's item being updated again, simply refer to the list item ID hidden field and use the "Update List Item" action along with that ID.

Hope this helps, good luck!

EDIT!

You could also do the reverse and store the ID of the original item in a hidden field in listXYZ itself. Then use the "current item id" from your trigger list to find the correct row in listXYZ. Either option works. This one may be "cleaner" depending on how you view it.